# Launching Edge Browser

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2010

Edge browser is launching but URL is not considered

Im trying to launch my code in Edge browser, So jus changing the code in Initazlizehooks.cs (Class Created to initialize all the diff browser).

Code:

```cs
Case BrowserType.Edge: 
  EdgeOptions options4 = new EdgeOptions(); 
  DriverContext.Driver = new EdgeDriver(); 
  DriverContext.Browser = new Browser(DriverContext.Driver); 
  DriverContext.Browser.Maximize(); 
  break;
```

Error:

```
A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL localhost:52094/session. The status of the exception was ReceiveFailure, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

Comment: Code:case BrowserType.Edge:
                    EdgeOptions options4 = new EdgeOptions();
                    DriverContext.Driver = new EdgeDriver();
                    DriverContext.Browser = new Browser(DriverContext.Driver);
                    DriverContext.Browser.Maximize();
                    break;

Comment: Error:A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:52094/session. The status of the exception was ReceiveFailure, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Comment: This should be in the question, not as comments [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57410042/edit) you question.

Comment: Which version of Edge and which version of EdgeDriver are you using? You'll need to make sure the version of EdgeDriver you are using supports the version of Edge you have installed on that machine.